# Generate Random with no repeating numbers

Tags: python

I want to make loop generate from random generator with no duplicate values like below:

```
1,4
1,2
1,3
1,1
1,7
1,9
1,8
2,5
2,2
2,1
2,3
2,4
2,5
2,7
```

What I mean is, that there are no duplicated value on the second value for each first value. And the value range for second value is from (1 to 10).

My code below still gives duplicated values:

```
import random
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(7):
        print(i, ',', random.randint(1,10))
```

any ideas on how to address this problems?
Any response really appreciated.

Comment: Well, where in your code are you doing anything to check if there are duplicates? You know your code is wrong, but where have you even made an attempt to filter duplicates?

Comment: i got no idea on how to check if there are duplicates, cheers

Comment: @JONPANTAU you want the value in first column to be 1 for seven unique value of second column then 2 for seven unique value right ?

Comment: The question is unclear: please edit it and provide a better specification of what is needed.

Comment: I can see duplicated values in the second position (`1,3` and `2,3`). Does that mean you _actually_ want no duplication for the whole tuple (so `1,3` and `2,3` are distinct 2-tuples) or no duplication in the second position _for a given value in the first position_ (ie, only one `1,3`), or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) which is the built-in way of generating non-repeating random elements from a population:

```
from random import sample

for i in range(1, 3):
    for j in sample(list(range(1, 11)), 7):
        print(i, ',', j)
        # 7 random non-repeating `j` from [1, 2, ..., 10]
```

For sampling 14 random elements from the entire pool of possible pairs, you can combine it with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

sample_pairs = sample(list(product(range(1, 3), range(1, 11))), 14)
#[(2, 10),
# (1, 1),
# (2, 7),
# (2, 9),
# (1, 10),
# (2, 5),
# (1, 2),
# (1, 9),
# (2, 4),
# (2, 3),
# (2, 2),
# (1, 8),
# (2, 8),
# (1, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

generate the product list and then shuffle it. It will contain unique values in tuple

```
from itertools import product
from random import shuffle
my_list= list((i,j) for i,j in product([1,2],range(1,10)) if i!=j)
shuffle(my_list)
print(my_list[:14]) # just pick random 14 pairs which are not duplicate
```

Correcting your code to check for duplicates. Although with expensive in operator

```
import random
intial_range=range(2)
for i in intial_range:
    count=0
    while count<7:
        temp = random.randint(1,10)
        if(temp not in intial_range):
            print(i, ',', temp)
            count+=1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

for i in range(2):
    j = 0
    nums = []
    while j != 7:
        num = random.randint(1,10)
        if num not in nums:
            print(i+1, ',', num)
            nums.append(num)
            j+=1
```

Comment: Please do not just provide a piece of code: explain how the code answers the question. If the question is ill-posed (as it is in this case, ask for improvements in the comments first - otherwise, you may be answering a question that is different from what the OP intended).

Comment: This isn't a brilliant piece of code. You should be using a `set` instead of a `list`, it separates the numbers with `" , "` instead of `","`, magic numbers abound... It's not a good example without an explanation, and not great even with one tbh. But it _definitely_ needs an explanation.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to make an empty array then append the number if not in the array else pass

Like this :

```
import random
my_numbers = []

for i in range(5):
    x = random.randint(0,19)
    if x not in my_numbers:
        my_numbers.append(x)
    else:
        pass
```